# Seg Fault when attempting to append strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to append a string to another one, and I'm getting a seg fault and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
typedef char * String;
String function(String str) {
    // Some variables here
    String current = "";
    String ch = "";

    //More code here
    while() {
        if() {
            current = malloc(strlen(current) + strlen(ch) + 1);
            strcat(current, ch);
        }
     ...
     }
}
```

I keep getting a seg fault even with the `strcat` line commented out, and vice versa with the `malloc` line. This is probably something painfully obvious that I'm missing, but could someone explain how to do this properly do this, and explain what I've done wrong?

Comment: current is not nul terminated after malloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current` is not '\0' terminated after `malloc`.
`strcat` is searching for this character to know where to append and segfaults doing this.

Your previous initialization of `current` has no meaning after `malloc` returns, it points to completely different part of uninitialized memory.
Can't tell for sure, but from what you provided my tip is to use `realloc` to extend size of `current`.

Answer (score 0):

After your `malloc` you are forgetting to fill the new allocated string with the previous `current` content - and you cannot do that because you've lost the reference to it (further, you are introudcing a memory leak because you are not freeing it. 
Try `realloc` instead - but first allocate `current` with `malloc`